# Local declaration of hides instance variable semantic issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5, appdelegate

I m need to access the appDelegate variables in all ViewControllers .So when I need it I m writing

```
     AppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     appDelegate.name=x;  //warning :Local declaration of appDelegate hides instance variable.
```

I access the appDelegate variables like this wherever necessary in methods.But I get a lot of warnings..How can I avoid them ?

Comment: @Vishal Except that the leading `*` is erroneous.

Comment: remove your AppDelegate  *appDelegate declaration from .h file yeah @interface block in your respective class.

Comment: otherwise write appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; instead of AppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
AppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

to

```
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```